# How to send score to database?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I'm writing application in Angular and Spring Boot. I don't know how send score of my test to database.

I log in first and after I do a test I want send score for this user who is logged, to database.

### Spring

```java
@PutMapping("/users/{login}/points")
public ResponseEntity<User> przeslijWynik(
    @PathVariable String login,
    @RequestParam ("points") int points) {
  User user = userRepository.findByLogin(login);
  user.setPoints(points); userRepository.save(user);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
}
```

### Angular

```js
sendScore() { 
  this.wynikService.przekazWynik(this.wynik, this.user).subscribe((data) => { 
    this.wynik.points = this.punkty;
    console.log(data);
  });
}

passResult(wynik: Wynik, user: User): Observable<Object> {
  return this.http.put(${this.url}/${user.login}, wynik.points);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Or in what way is it not working? I'm assuming angulars `http.put` expects valid JSON as second parameter and `wynik.points` is just a number

Comment: Errors are not getting. Just this score is not added to my database for logged user and wynik.points is a number.

Answer (score 1):

By passing just a number as second parameter to angulars `HttpClient.put` the request body will simply consist of this number and nothing else.

What you want instead is to pass JSON in the request body telling spring which value should be mapped to `points`.

Something like this should work:

```
passResult(wynik: Wynik, user: User): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.put(${this.url}/${user.login}, {points: wynik.points});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using  @RequestParam for points so you request shoud go to

/users/{login}/points?points={points}

```
passResult(wynik: Wynik, user: User): Observable<Object> {
  return this.http.put(${this.url}/${user.login}/points?points={wynik.points});
}
```